# Cannot use custom template in Bookdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

I am creating an R package which is relying on [Bookdown](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown) to create PDF books out of `.Rmd` files. I want to use a custom latex template. So, according to [Bookdown doc section on templates](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/templates.html) and [Pandoc's doc on templates](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates), I have created, in my project, the following structure:

```
myproj/
├── inst/
│   ├── examples/
│   |   ├── firstbook/
│   |   |   ├── index.Rmd
│   |   |   ├── ...
│   ├── rmarkdown/
│   |   ├── templates/
│   |   |   ├── book_tex/
│   |   |   |   ├── resources/
│   |   |   |   |   ├── template.tex
│   |   |   |   ├── skeleton/
│   |   |   |   |   ├── monograph.cls
│   |   |   |   |   ├── bibliography.bib
│   |   |   |   |   ├── skeleton.Rmd
│   |   |   |   ├── template.yaml
├── R/
│   ├── format.R
│   └── render.R
└── DESCRIPTION
```

#### Template artifacts

The new template is called `book_tex`, I have created a folder with this name under `inst/rmarkdown/templates`.

**template.tex** is:

```
% !TeX program = pdfLaTeX
\documentclass{monograph}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{newtxmath}       % Times Roman as basic font

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\author{ $for(authors)$ $authors.name$ \and $endfor$ }
\title{$title$}
$if(subtitle)$
    \subtitle{$subtitle$}
$endif$

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

$body$

\printindex

\end{document}
```

**template.yaml** is:

```yaml
name: PDF Book
description: >
 Template for creating a TEX book
create_dir: true
```

**skeleton.Rmd** is:

```
---
title: Title here
subtitle: Do you have a subtitle? If so, write it here

thanks: | 
    Grants or other notes about the article that should go on the front 
    page should be placed here. General acknowledgments should be placed at the
    end of the article.
authors: 
- name: Author 1
  address: Department of YYY, University of XXX
  email: abc@def

- name: Author 2
  address: Department of ZZZ, University of WWW
  email: djf@wef

keywords:
- key
- dictionary
- word  

abstract: |
  The text of your abstract.  150 -- 250 words.

output: myprojpkg::book_tex
---

# Introduction {#intro}

Your text comes here. Separate text sections with

# Section title {#sec:1}

Some text.

## Subsection title {#sec:2}

Some other text.
```

#### Building

I have created a custom format which basically sets my custom template in file `format.R`:

```r
book_tex_format <- function(...) {
  rmarkdown::pdf_document(..., template = "book_tex")
}
```

And then, in `render.R`, I invoke Bookdown from inside my package's example dir (working directory is `myproj/inst/examples/firstbook`) in RStudio:

```r
bookdown::render_book(".", book_tex_format())
```

Which gives me error:

> "C:/PROGRA~1/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS _index_merged.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output _index_merged.tex --self-contained --template book_tex --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --lua-filter "C:/Users/me/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:/Users/me/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/latex-div.lua" 
>   Could not find data file templates\book_tex.latex

I have then tried:

```r
bookdown::render_book(".", rmarkdown::pdf_document(template="../../rmarkdown/templates/book_tex/resources/template.tex"))
```

Which seemed to work but then gave me error:

> "C:/PROGRA~1/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS _index_merged.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output _index_merged.tex --self-contained --template "....\rmarkdown\templates\book_tex\resources\template.tex" --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --lua-filter "C:/Users/me/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:/Users/me/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/latex-div.lua" 
>   ! LaTeX Error: File `monograph.cls' not found.

I have mimicked the structure by looking at how RMarkdown and Bookdown are doing stuff. But it seems like it is not good enough. I am very frustrated, this part of the API is poorly documented and I don't get how I am supposed to make it work.

How should I invoke `render_book` in order to pass a template?

```r
bookdown::render_book(".", !!HERE!!)
```

---

#### Another attempt

I have come across function `rmarkdown::draft` which seems to be the recommended way of using a template. So I did invoke (working directory: `myproj/inst/examples`):

```r
rmarkdown::draft("mybook2", "book_tex", "myprojpkg", TRUE)
```

Note that my package is called `myprojpkg` (in `DESCRIPTION` file). This command works fine and actusally emits this folder:

```
myproj/
├── inst/
│   ├── examples/
│   |   ├── firstbook/
│   |   ├── mybook2/
│   |   |   |   ├── monograph.cls
│   |   |   |   ├── bibliography.bib
│   |   |   |   ├── mybook.Rmd
│   ├── rmarkdown/
│   |   ├── templates/
│   |   |   ├── book_tex/
│   |   |   |   ├── ...
├── R/
│   ├── ...
└── DESCRIPTION
```

Where `mybook.Rmd` is `skeleton.Rmd` renamed. So the command is correctly taking the template I defined in my package and creating the directory structure ready to be submitted to `bookdown::render_book`, however the problem is that calling it does not get me any error, but does not apply the correct template (`template.tex` inside `book_tex`). The command here relies on the content of `skeleton.Rmd` where it specifies the template to use in the yaml header, but that template is not found somehow and not applied :(

---

#### (friendly) Feedback on Bookdown documentation

I have to say that this part of custom templates needs better documenting because it is not immediate how a developer is supposed to structure the project to make things work with custom templates.

**EDIT** I have actually found some good documentation about these topics on the [rmarkdown::draft function](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/R/draft.R). My feedback would be to make it more visible in the help pages in the sections about templates. Now this chunk (quite important chunk) of doc is basically hidden.

Comment: The structure you set up is meant for a package containing your template. A more informative description can be found here https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/document-templates.html and https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/new-formats.html. But you are right. There is still room for improvement concerning the docs.(;

Comment: @stefan Thanks for your comment. I can see that basically I need to invoke `rmarkdown::draft` to _deploy_ the template! Is that right?

Comment: Nop. First you have to put your template in a package. Then can you choose your template via `rmarkdown::draft("my_article.Rmd", template = "NAME_OF_MY_TEMPLATE", package = "MY_TEMPLATE_PACKAGE")`.

Comment: @stefan Can't I simply put the templates in the same package where I want to use them and invoke: `rmarkdown::draft("my_article.Rmd", template = "NAME_OF_MY_TEMPLATE", package = ".")`?

Comment: Really don't know whether this will work. In my case I simply followed the docs and set up a package with a html and a word template for our company reports. Works fine besides setting up a word template is a real pain. (;

Answer (score 1):

After analyzing the code and playing a little bit with Bookdown and Rmarkdown, and as it also shown in some comments I received (thanks @stefan), I came to the conclusion that the template, and all its resources, need to be in the same folder where your `.Rmd` files are. This is actually reflected by the presence of function [`draft`](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/R/draft.R) in Rmarkdown which accomplishes this target. So my folder structure would eventually become:

```
myproj/
├── monograph.cls
├── bibliography.bib
├── template.tex
├── mybook.Rmd
├── index.Rmd
├── _bookdown.yaml
```

From here, I would open RStudio and change folder to `myproj`, or open an R shell and change working directory to `myproj` by issuing: `setwd("path/to/myproj")`. I would then invoke command:

```r
bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", bookdown::pdf_book(template = "template.tex"))
```

This will start the machine and get your PDF created.

---

#### Warning: theorems and other environments

If your template imports `amsthm` or other environments that define blocks like `theorem` or similar, Bookdown will fail. Bookdown will automatically append definitions for theorems in the Latex template your provide (a copy of it generated in the intermediate folder). You need to apply [this fix](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/417) to make things work (in your `index.Rmd`):

````
---
title: My book
author: Me
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
options(bookdown.post.latex = function(x) {
  from <- grep("usepackage\\{amsthm\\}", x)
  to <- grep("newtheorem\\*\\{solution", x)
  x <- x[-c(from:to)]
})
```
````